# Problems getting a json document with Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have the following Angular example that gets a json document from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/master/bower.json` and shows the response.toString() in a template like `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  // url = 'http://s331998788.online.de:5080/dict.json';
  url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/master/bower.json';

  constructor(http: Http) {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    http.get(this.url).subscribe(t => this.title = t.toString());
  }

}
```

`t.toString()` returns `Response with status: 200 OK for URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/master/bower.json` to `{{title}}`.

If instead I get the url `http://s331998788.online.de:5080/dict.json` it seems that `t.toString()` does not return nothing to `{{title}}` and the template simply displays `app works!`.

What is wrong with this json document?

The relevant difference seems to me that the working page has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and the other not. If this is the source of the problem, how can I tell `http` to get also those documents?

Asking the header infos with `curl -i` we get the following:

```
$ curl -i 'http://s331998788.online.de:5080/dict.json'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Zope/(2.13.21, python 2.7.5, linux2) ZServer/1.1
Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 23:01:32 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 23:01:23 GMT
Content-Length: 46
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Ranges: bytes

  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 21
  }


$ curl -i 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/master/bower.json'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
ETag: "007371a434d2486e54fb403ff912ec202322d603"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: max-age=300
X-Geo-Block-List:
X-GitHub-Request-Id: 2C5E:674E:431187:459555:5903C9F0
Content-Length: 89
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 23:02:09 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-hhn1523-HHN
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1493420529.409818,VS0,VE110
Vary: Authorization,Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Fastly-Request-ID: 9270c2ab79c2d179ec005957794044dc1796841b
Expires: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 23:07:09 GMT
Source-Age: 0

{
  "name": "angular",
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: http.get() actually encapsulates a Response object. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data

Comment: Unless the server has authorized it, JavaScript served by a domain can't load anything from another domain. That's what, I guess, is the problem. It would help if you told us what the problem is: what do you get, what do you see in the console, the network panel, etc.

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean, exactly? how are you trying to consume the data?  if it is an object, you can't subscribe to it, but you should see the data in the `response` object....  Also, an Object "dictionary" is still JSON.

Comment: @Claies: I've reformulate the question for clarity

Comment: so you are trying to do a cross domain request?  does the site allow these kind of requests?  In other words, is CORS set up?

Comment: @Claies: both requests go to other domains! The relevant difference seems to me that the working page has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and the other not. I've updated the question.

Comment: That's what we're telling you from the beginning: if the server you're trying to access doesn't allow accesses from other domains, you just can't access them. The browser will prevent it. That's what CORS is all about.

Comment: @JBNizet: The servers I'm responsible to have CORS already enabled. But what I try is to make a request to a server not under my responsibility. Is there really no way to simply request a json page with JavaScript/TypeScript?

Comment: No, there is no way.

Comment: If there was a way to access resources without CORS configured, then CORS wouldn't be necessary in the first place.  There is more to CORS than just setting it to `*` and then walking away;  **Most** CORS configurations are to allow only specific domains, to protect data from being siphoned off at random.

Answer (score 0):

The `Http.get` method returns a response object (as wannadream said in the comments).

```
http.get(this.url).subscribe(t => this.title = t.toString());
```

this shows the string representation of the response object, if you want to see the json, you have to either use `t.text()` (gets the raw text of the body) or `t.json()` (parses the raw text into an object).

You should add an error subscription to see why you don't have anything in title:

```
http.get(this.url).subscribe(t => this.title = t.toString(), error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: I've updated the question.The relevant difference seems to me that the working page has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and the other not. I've updated the question.